# Adding new option to select in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, activerecord

I currently have a vendor, which can have any number of tags attached to it. However, I also want the user to be able to add extra tags on the form. I had previously done this with `fields_for` and text fields in the form, and `accepts_nested_attributes` in the controller, but this led to tags getting duplicated when a tag with the same name was added to two different vendors. I know this happened because each vendor could only see the tags that it owned, so it did not know the IDs of the other tags.

Now, I have switched to a `select`, which lists all possible tags, and pass in a list of ownership IDs to the controller. However, I cannot add new tags anymore, since it cannot find the IDs of the new tags if they aren't added to the database first. It seems that I cannot use `fields_for` to build the options within the `select`, so I'm kind of stuck on how to handle this. I've looked into using AJAX to create the tag using the `remote: true` option inside `form_for`, but it seems that forms within forms are not supported.

Here are the basic model relationships:

```rb
class Vendor < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :vendor_ownerships
  has_many :ownerships, through: :vendor_ownerships
end
```

```rb
class Ownership < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :vendor_ownerships
  has_many :vendors, through: :vendor_ownerships
end
```

```rb
class VendorOwnership < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :vendor
  belongs_to :ownership
end
```

Here is my form partial (simplified). It currently tries to use nested forms, but it does not work.

```
= form_for @vendor do |f|
  #form_elements_div
    .form_group.element_div
      = f.label :name
      = f.text_field :name

    #ownerships.element_div
      = f.collection_select :ownership_ids, Ownership.all, :id, :name, {}, {multiple: true}

    #new_ownerships.element_div
      -# How do I add the new tag/ownership here?
      = form_for :ownership, url: ownerships_path, remote: true do |ff|
        = ff.text_field :new_ownership_field
        = ff.submit

    #submit_div.form_group
      = f.submit class: 'btn btn-success'
```

Theoretically, the nested form for adding a new tag would trigger the controller action `create` inside the `Ownership` model, but the submit button for that form always triggers the `create` for the outer `Vendor` model.

Edit: Here is the HTML body currently created by my code.

```html
<body>
  <body id='vendorsBody'>
    <div id='form_div'>
      <h2>Edit Vendor</h2>
      <form class="edit_vendor" id="edit_vendor_1" action="/vendors/1" accept-charset="UTF-8" method="post">
        <input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="&#x2713;" />
        <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="patch" />
        <input type="hidden" name="authenticity_token" value="PzG968HknJ5wCYt37g7RL8J4/00rmcnIO6T02owt5HBh9FUsXfWd00WZW1k/vM+o4RktfbKPBEcWk4BdCfYnhg==" />

        <div id='form_elements_div'>
          <div class='form_group element_div'>
            <label for="vendor_name">Name</label>
            <input type="text" value="Vendor 1" name="vendor[name]" id="vendor_name" />
          </div>

          <div class='element_div' id='ownerships'>
            <input name="vendor[ownership_ids][]" type="hidden" value="" />
              <select multiple="multiple" name="vendor[ownership_ids][]" id="vendor_ownership_ids">
                <option selected="selected" value="1">Type 1</option>
                <option selected="selected" value="2">Type 2</option>
                <option selected="selected" value="3">Type 3</option>
              </select>
          </div>

          <div class='element_div' id='new_ownerships'>
            <form action="/ownerships" accept-charset="UTF-8" data-remote="true" method="post">
              <input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="&#x2713;" />
              <input type="text" name="ownership[new_ownership_field]" id="ownership_new_ownership_field" />
              <input type="submit" name="commit" value="Save Ownership" data-disable-with="Save Ownership" />
            </form>
          </div>
          <div class='form_group' id='submit_div'>
            <input type="submit" name="commit" value="Update Vendor" class="btn btn-success" data-disable-with="Update Vendor" />
            <button class='btn btn-danger' id='cancel_button' onclick='confirmVendorCancel()' type='button'>Cancel</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </body>
</body>
```

Comment: nested form is a bad choice I reckon. If you want to ajax submit new tag/ownership, you can do that by listening to inner button click instead.

Comment: @kasperite is right. Try to debug this and see what HTML code is generated by your form builder

Comment: I just made an edit showing what the HTML code looks like. It seems like the inner form points to the correct controller method, but the page still treats the submit button as updating the vendor instead of creating the tag/ownership.

Comment: submit button always targets ancestor form unless you set its `form` attribute manually(https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button#Attributes). That's probably what you want.

Comment: It seems like setting the `form` attribute only works if the forms are not nested (i.e. multiple consecutive forms on a page). I'm going to look into listening to the button click and making an AJAX call to the controller `create` method. I guess I'm just a little frustrated that Rails already has a decent way to submit forms via AJAX with the `remote: true` option, but it doesn't work for nested forms.